# Choosing RAID mode rather than AHCI/SATA mode?

Tags: bios, raid, sata, ahci

Currently studying how computers work, I came across the last paragraph of the answer of this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/what-does-ahci-mode-ide-mode-raid-mode-sata-mean/d622d5cd-41c4-4b84-90ef-cea69aa47089?auth=1):

> Many SATA controllers can enable AHCI separately or in conjunction with RAID support. Intel recommends choosing RAID mode on their motherboards, which also enables AHCI, rather than AHCI/SATA mode for maximum flexibility (in case you ever want to build a RAID array), since there are some issues that occurs, usually BSOD, when you choose a different mode once an operating system has already been installed.

I don't understand how the author compares RAID+AHCI to AHCI+SATA? or AHCI+SATA over just AHCI?(From the second sentence: "Intel recommends choosing RAID mode on their motherboards, which also enables AHCI, rather than AHCI/SATA mode")

To my understanding:

- RAID is about configuring different storage devices to act like one (through the system setup). So it's on software + hardware level.
- SATA is the combination of a plug + cable + socket. So hardware.
- AHCI is a piece of hardware which allows your OS to communicate with your storage system. There is also an AHCI mode. So hardware + software.

I don't understand "choosing RAID over AHCI/SATA" or "choosing AHCI over both AHCI/SATA" in this context... Let's say you have 4 drives, configured as a RAID-6 array. Those drives will be physically linked to your motherboard with SATA plugs/sockets, and if you have an OS more recent than Vista, you will likely run AHCI on system setup for efficient communication between your RAID-6 array and your OS. I don't understand how they compare: one is array of drives, one is physical plug+cable+socket, and one allows communication between OS and storage.

In this context, it makes no sense to me to choose RAID over AHCI/SATA or AHCI over AHCI+SATA (depending on the different ways I tried to read this)... Or maybe I'm reading the sentence the wrong way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`which also enables AHCI` is in a `()`, and by `AHCI/SATA` he merely means `AHCI mode` can also be called `(native) SATA mode` as opposed to `IDE/PATA/legacy mode`. You were simply reading it the wrong way. The main idea was just that `RAID mode` essentially "encompasses" (the features of) `AHCI mode`, like the former is a "superset" of the latter. (I never cared enough to find out whether that is an accurate idea though.)

Comment: The truth is, if you are not gonna make a (fake) RAID, the main concern about the choice is that you'll be using different driver for each of them, which might have their own pitfall / hiccup or difference in terms of quality of code / maintenance.